# Bind unbind jquery script on browser resize

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I am trying to stop a script running if the browser width exceeds 640px, basically if the browser is more than 640px, then it should show a grid, if it's less then 640px then show a slideshow.

The following code allows me to load a script if the browser is less than 640px else do another script.

```
var currentState = false;

function setSize() {

    var state = $(window).width() < 640;
    if (state != currentState) {
        currentState = state;
        if (state) {

        } 
        else {


        }
    }
}

setSize();
$(window).on('resize', setSize);
```

Here's the actual code I want to run only when the browser is less than 640px

```
window.sliderInit = (function (window, document, undefined) {

        'use strict';

        // Feature Test
        if ( 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach ) {

            // SELECTORS
            var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('[data-slider]');
            var mySwipe = Array;


            // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS

            // Add class to HTML element to activate conditional CSS
            document.documentElement.className += ' js-slider';

            // Activate all sliders
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, function (slider, index) {

                // SELECTORS

                var slideCount = slider.querySelector('[data-slider-count]'); // Slider count wrapper
                var slideNav = slider.querySelector('[data-slider-nav]'); // Slider nav wrapper


                // METHODS

                // Display count of slides
                var createSlideCount = function () {
                    // Variables
                    var slideTotal = mySwipe[index].getNumSlides();
                    var slideCurrent = mySwipe[index].getPos();

                    // Content
                    if ( slideCount !== null ) {
                        slideCount.innerHTML = slideCurrent + ' of ' + slideTotal;
                    }
                };

                // Display Slider navigation
                var createNavButtons = function () {
                    if ( slideNav !== null ) {
                        slideNav.innerHTML = '<a data-slider-nav-prev href="#">Previous</a> | <a data-slider-nav-next href="#">Next</a>';
                    }
                };

                // Stop YouTube and Vimeo videos from playing when leaving the slide
                var stopVideo = function () {
                    var currentSlide = mySwipe[index].getPos() - 1;
                    var iframe = slider.querySelector( '[data-index="' + currentSlide + '"] iframe');
                    var video = slider.querySelector( '[data-index="' + currentSlide + '"] video' );
                    if ( iframe !== null ) {
                        var iframeSrc = iframe.src;
                        iframe.src = iframeSrc;
                    }
                    if ( video !== null ) {
                        video.pause();
                    }
                };

                // Handle next button
                var handleNextBtn = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    stopVideo();
                    mySwipe[index].next();
                };

                // Handle previous button
                var handlePrevBtn = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    stopVideo();
                    mySwipe[index].prev();
                };

                // Handle keypress
                var handleKeypress = function (event) {
                    if ( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
                        mySwipe[index].prev();
                    }
                    if ( event.keyCode == 39) {
                        mySwipe[index].next();
                    }
                };


                // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS

                // Activate Slider
                mySwipe[index] = Swipe(slider, {
                    continuous: true,
                    callback: function(index, elem) {
                        createSlideCount(); // Update with new position on slide change
                    }
                });

                // Create slide count and nav
                createSlideCount();
                createNavButtons();
                var btnNext = slider.querySelector('[data-slider-nav-next]'); // Next slide button
                var btnPrev = slider.querySelector('[data-slider-nav-prev]'); // Previous slide button

                // Toggle Previous & Next Buttons
                if ( btnNext ) {
                    btnNext.addEventListener('click', handleNextBtn, false);
                }
                if ( btnPrev ) {
                    btnPrev.addEventListener('click', handlePrevBtn, false);
                }

                // Toggle Left & Right Keypress
                window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeypress, false);

            });

        }

    })(window, document);
```

This works up to a point, if you open the http://jsfiddle.net/xc2cgs6b/show and your browser is more than 640px it will show a grid, if you then resize the browser to less than 640px it will show a slideshow, so far it works fine, but once you resize it over 640px again it should go back to the grid but it doesn't, also if you open the browser less than 640px, it doesn't work at all.

Here's a fiddle in code view http://jsfiddle.net/xc2cgs6b/

I'm told that bind and unbind could work but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: One error is caused by calling `setSize()` (and `Swipe` inside it) before this `Swipe` if defined. Just place `setSize();` to the end of script. The main problem (not showing grid back) exists due to fact that you actually **do nothing** to reach this aim (I suppose these lines `$('.swipe-container').removeAttr('id');` and `$('.swipe-container').unbind();` are deadly not sufficient to get all back as it was).

Comment: Can I be cheeky and ask if you could update the fiddle, I'm fairly new to jquery and I think I might edit it wrong

Comment: It will be difficult to understand all code (about 100 lines) inside `if (state) { }`. If it is your code, you should know what should be undone. If it is not your code, ask code's owner or start learning JavaScript (not jQuery in particular, because there is a few code written using jQuery).